# AJAX dropdown lists dependent & dynamic

Tags: forms, ajax

I have tried the example I found on [Dynamic select list in the form API (dependent dropdown list)?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/56531/dynamic-select-list-in-the-form-api-dependent-dropdown-list) but I did not get it to work properly. The first list populates, but I can not fill the second one with values that are different depending on the first select.

```
function formtutorial_form(&$form_state) {
  // Connection settings here!!! Then two queries below.
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT productID, ProductName, oil_ID FROM tb_Products");

  if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $productlist = array();
    foreach ($stmt as $row) {
      $productlist[$row->productID] = $row->ProductName;
    }
  }

  $productIDselected = $form_state['values']['Products'];
  $stmt7 = $conn->prepare("SELECT oil_ID, OilName FROM tb_Oils WHERE oil_ID = $productIDselected ");
  if ($stmt7->execute()) {
    $stmt7->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $oillists = array();
    foreach ($stmt7 as $row) {
      $oillists[$row->oil_ID] = $row->OilName;
    }
  }

  $form['Products'] = array(
    '#type'=>'select',
    '#title' => t('Products'),
    '#options' => $productlist,
    '#multiple' => FALSE,
    '#attributes'=> array('size' => 0), 
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => '_ajaxfunction',
      'wrapper' => 'divaroundseconddropdown'
    ),
  );

  $form['Oils'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Oils'),
    '#options' => $oillists,
    '#multiple' => false,
    '#prefix' => '<div id="divaroundseconddropdown">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#productlist' => array(
      'visible' =>array(
        'input[name="productname"]' => array(
          'value' => $productlist
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );

function _ajaxfunction($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['Oils'];
}
```

Comment: can you include you ajax function? also, besides the point you should consider adding your database to the drupal connection and use it rather than connecting through PDO, it is much easier with Drupal, see [this post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45199/using-db-query-or-db-select-to-connect-to-multiple-databases)

Comment: @longboardnode I added the function at the bottom, I followed a stack exchange question see link in my question. Above is the code I shall use.

Comment: @longboardnode http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75211/how-to-display-the-selected-value-from-drop-down-box-by-using-form-api/75230#75230 trying this, it is the same question, but looks more like it will work

Comment: try this post http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10112/dynamic-select-list-in-the-form-dependent-dropdown/10115#10115

Comment: The code you are showing is not complete (see the lines before `function _ajaxfunction($form, $form_state)`). If `formtutorial_form(&$form_state)` is a form building function, then it is missing an argument, and it should return a value.